# Aparecer Icone da extensão conforme a extensão do arquivo (doc, xls, pdf)

Tags: php, html, jquery, arquivo, icons

Estou com uma demanda de um sistema de php.

Estou listando documentos de um determinado diretório que está no servidor em minha página html

```
  <div class="tab-pane" id="docs">


                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Documento</th>


                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php
                                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gr_documento 
                                                                                                                        WHERE id_entidade_documento = ". $_GET['id']."
                                                                                                                        AND tipo = 1");
                                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                               
                                    ?>

                                    <tr>
                                                                                <td><a href="/upload/docs/<?php echo $row['novo_nome']?>" target=“_blank” ><?php echo $row['nome_documento']?></a></td>

                                    </tr>

                                     <?php
                                     }
                                     ?>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>


                            </div>
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível eu criar uma coluna na esquerda só que aparecendo um ícone conforme a extensão. Ex:

Se o arquivo tiver a extensão .pdf apresentar um ícone de ligado ao PDF
Se o arquivo tiver a extensão .xls apresentar um ícone de ligado ao Excel
Se o arquivo tiver a extensão .doc apresentar um ícone de ligado ao Word
Se o arquivo tiver a extensão .txt apresentar um ícone de ligado ao TXT

Não sei se existe alguma função que execute esse processo. Podem me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função para retornar a imagem associada ao tipo de um arquivo recebido como parametro. Explicando melhor, você cria uma função que recebe como parametro o caminho para um arquivo e retorna o caminho de uma imagem associada a esse arquivo (de acordo com o icone). Então poderia ser algo assim:

```
function imagemMimeType($caminhoArquivo){
     $tipos = [
    'text/plain' => 'imagens/icone1.png', 
    'image/png' => 'imagens/icone2.png', 
    'image/jpeg' => 'imagens/icone3.png', 
    'application/pdf' => 'imagens/icone4.png'];

     //veja mais tipos em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mime-content-type.php

     $tipo = mime_content_type ($caminhoArquivo);
     return $tipos[$tipo];
}
```

E dentro do seu laço while você conseguiria descobrir qual icone deveria estar associado com seu arquivos. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
//não necessariamente precisa de extensão
//echo imagemMimeType('caminho_do_arquivo.entensao');
$caminhoIcone = imagemMimeType("/upload/docs/<?php echo $row['novo_nome']?>");
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou realizar um teste :)